# Through Apex Item Checkbox checks want to store values in Item field

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I used Interactive report APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(p_idx => 1, p_value => ST.ID, p_attributes => DECODE(ST.IS_HEADER_ROW ,'Y', 'DISABLED',NULL)).
[image]
And I want to use highlighted IDs depending upon checks in Row ID field in Comma delimited format DYNAMICALLY.

Further I will use that Row IDs value in another region report and will update values in DB after few validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button press, you could run this JavaScript which concatenates all nominated checkboxes into a delimited string.

```
$s('P1_ROWIDS',
  $("[name='f01']").map(function(){
     return this.value;
  }).get().join(",")
);
```

Then use the following query to find all the records matching values in that string using this, or your version's equivalent.

```
select * from your_table
where id in (select column_value from apex_string.split(:P1_ROWIDS))
```

This can all happen without submitting the page.

Comment: There is no button on each click on chcekbox JS should work dynamically. Should I place it in mail page JS code

Comment: Previous code written on the main page which was working for single check for checkbox marked as class= boxes. Please have a look and advise:

`var htmldb_delete_message='"DELETE_CONFIRM_MSG"';



$(document).on('change', '.boxes', function() {

  //debugger;

  if (this.checked)

  {

    //alert($(this).val());
    $(".boxes").prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    apex.item( "P11_ROW_PK" ).setValue( $(this).val() );
  }
  else
  {
    apex.item( "P11_ROW_PK" ).setValue('');
  }
});`

Comment: I wasn't sure when you wanted this executed, so I meant some conceptual button. If it needs to happen as you check the box, then you could have a dynamic action on click of the relevant jQuery selector. You could also consider something like this http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html

Comment: That code is unreadable, I would suggest extending your question.

Comment: Your JS code concatenates all nominated checkboxes and not the ones which are selected by checks. Can you please help me with the same please...

Comment: When I put Jquery selector in Dynamic Action as input:checkbox it works but when I apply any filter it stops working on selection. @Scott

Comment: Ahh, yes. I got that wrong. I will adjust my answer to another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will fetch only those IDs which are checked in checkbox in comma delimited format (Note: this can be included in DA on any button which should be clicked after selection of multiple rows via checkbox)

`$s('P11_ROW_PK', $("[name='f01']:checked").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get().join(","));`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.