# Classic report issue with multiple inputs with IN statement

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to refresh a report with dynamic action. And get the following errors:

{'dialogue': {'uv': true, 'line': [{'V': "failure of Widget}]}}
ORA-20876: stop the engine of the APEX.
classic_report"}]}}

I think its an issue with string which can't take `and ST.ID IN (:P11_ROW_PK)` in sql query.

Please suggest a workaround for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where REGEXP_LIKE(CUSTOMER_ID, '^('|| REPLACE(:P4_SEARCH,',','|') ||')$')`
Above code will act same as APEX_STRING only if you are using lower version Apex

Answer (score 0):

This question requires the context you've provided in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63627447/527513

If P11_ROW_PK is a delimited list of IDs, then you must structure your query accordingly, not expect the IN statement to deconstruct a bind variable containing a string.

Try this instead

```
select * from your_table
where st.id in (select column_value from apex_string.split(:P11_ROW_PK))
```

Comment: Will this be hard coded, I can see error even when I chose Generic column in report:
`select column_value from apex_string.split(:P11_ROW_PK)` @Scott

Comment: What do you mean 'hardcoded'? It takes the string that's in your bind variable, and splits it into multiple rows of one column. You can optionally specify your delimiter.

Comment: It gives error: `report error: ORA-00904: "APEX_STRING"."SPLIT": invalid identifier`
I think Apex 4.2 doesn't support APEX_STRING function need to find another solution... @Scott

Comment: String_to_table does a similar thing, but you'd need to wrap this in a pipelined function to be able to use it in SQL. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-EB21E226-E1F6-42B6-A48D-D9777C9D79E0.htm#AEAPI185

Comment: Thanks Scott, one more solution I got from link: http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2017/02/